# hasClass not working in IE9. what is the replacement or possible solution?

Tags: jquery

what is the alternative for hasClass in IE9 as it is not working.
I have defined some class on body and via jquery i am checking like
$(body).hasClass('myclassname').

It is not working in IE9.
what is the possible solution?

Comment: Can you provide your markup so we can see it's not working and you just haven't made a mistake?

Comment: hasClass should work fine

Comment: Post your actual code and the error message, if any. Both jQ 1 and 2 support IE9, so it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

ELEMENT.classList.contains('CLASS NAME') should work.
On your case body.classList.Contains('CLASSNAME') should do the trick

You should try to write vanilla js whenever possible since jquery always has an overhead